# Mvc.JQuery.DataTables column filters stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5.2, mvc.jquery.datatables

I believe this happened since my last NuGet package upgrade from `1.3.42` to `1.3.44`.

Report.cshtml:

```
@using Company.Controllers
@using Mvc.JQuery.DataTables
@using Mvc.JQuery.DataTables.Serialization

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Report";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/CSS/mvcdatatables")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mvcdatatables")
}

<div>
    <h1>Report for @ViewBag.ProjectName</h1>
</div>

@{
    var vm = Html.DataTableVm("table-id", (ProjectsController p) => p.GetReportData(null));

    vm.Dom = "Blfrtip";
    vm.LengthMenu = LengthMenuVm.Default();
    vm.PageLength = 25;
    vm.ColVis = false;
    vm.UseColumnFilterPlugin = true;
    vm.TableTools = true;
}

@Html.Partial("DataTable", vm)
```

When I enter any search term into the column filters, no filtering is happening any more. What I see in my GetReportData is that `DataTablesParam` does not have any `sSearchValues` filled in any more.

```
public DataTablesResult<VariableModel> GetReportDataCore(DataTablesParam dataTableParam, /* ... params omitted */)
{
    ...
    reportItems = ...  // Details doesn't matter how I obtain these, it works, the view lists the name value pairs
    var queryable = reportItems.InterceptWith(new SetComparerExpressionVisitor(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    return DataTablesResult.Create(queryable, dataTableParam, (ResponseOptions<VariableModel>)null);
}
```

After the `1.3.44` upgrade I tried:

```
@{
    var vm = Html.DataTableVm("table-id", (ProjectsController p) => p.GetReportData(null));

    vm.Dom = "Blfrtip";
    vm.LengthMenu = LengthMenuVm.Default();
    vm.PageLength = 25;
    vm.ColVis = false;
    vm.Filter = true;
    vm.ShowFilterInput = true;
    vm.UseColumnFilterPlugin = true;
    vm.TableTools = true;
    vm.FilterOn("VariableName").Text().FilterOn("Value").Text();  // Even this
}
```

What should I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a side effect of a missing file in the package: https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables/issues/148.

There's already a new `NuGet` package available (v `1.3.45`) which solves the problem: https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables/issues/149